# How do I do I unwrap from a point of view?

Tags: uv

How do I unwrap this object from my point of view, so that is perfectly aligned with the mesh behind it?

As you can tell in the following image, I tried my best to position it myself, but took a long time to get it how it looks. Any tricks or tips?

Thanks for your time.

[image]

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/30a1c83b317b8ceee24f03c5320becc5.png]
[image]

///
Edit: I was told I missed some details so here some more
https://i.gyazo.com/45f9298ce16cfe784d6f30ebdf7e1df2.png
You See this tiny cube that out of line with the mesh behind it we will call the mesh behind it mesh1 and the tiny cube that out of line mesh2
///
So I want mesh2 uvmap to be aline with mesh1 uv map perfectly without affecting mesh1 uvmap I hope this make since 
thank you for your time once again

Comment: Hello :). What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It is not really clear. And why are you not happy with your result?

Comment: Could you please also rephrase the question? That'll increase your chance of getting help...

Comment: cant you press 7 to go into top ortho and then when uv unwrapping go ''project from view'' with the meshes on top of each other

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a descriptive title, also describe what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Okay I'm sorry If I didn't say something correctly I'm a bit of a newbie blender I will update my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

- Select your objects and go to edit mode
- Select all faces of the both objects and switch to Top view
- From the menu select **UV -> Project From View**
- Switch to object mode and create a material for one of the objects
- Add your texture to the material
- Make sure you create a **Texture Coordinate** node and connect the **UV** slot to the **Vector** slot of your image texture.
- Apply the same material to the other object.

[image]

### Edit:

This was added to the question:
"I don't want to affect the plane UV map"

In this case you can use the **Data Transfer** modifier on your Cube to transfer the UVs form the Plane to the Cube (I used a Torus instead, it's a bit more visible)

- Position the Cube somewhere above the Plane
- Use **Data Transfer modifier** on the Cube
- In the modifier settings as the **Source** select your **Plane**
- Check **Face Corner Data** with **Nearest Face Interpolated** settings
- Click on **UVs**
- You might need to click **Generate Data Layers**

For the Data Transfer modifier to work properly you will need more **edges/subdivision on your Plane**.
If you don't apply the modifier you can move your Cube and the UV data will adapt to the new position.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Alternatively you can use the UV project modifier and use the camera as projector.

Comment: I don't want to affect the plane UV map though that's the problem

Comment: I see. I adapted my answer. This way you can preserve the plane UV's, but the plane should have better tessellation, otherwise it won't transfer the UV's properly.

Comment: Thank you very much this should help